# Ordenar cadastro pelo nome em ordem alfabética

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho alguns cadastros que tem como opção filtrar por ondem alfabética pelo nome.. Eu insiro esses cadastros através do append assim:

```
$(".listagem").append(
    `<div class="row" id="corpo-cartoes">
        <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card">
                <a href="cartao.html#${lastId}">

                   <div class="card-image">

                      <div class="gradient-cartao-lista"></div>

                      <img src="${capa}">

                      <span class="card-title"><h1>${data.card.empresa}</h1><p>${data.card.code}</p></span>

                   </div>
                </a>
                <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">

                   <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>

                   <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>

                   <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>

                   <a href="cadastro-cartao.html#${lastId}"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>

                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>`
);
```

Visualmente fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ordená-los em ordem alfabética pelo nome.

No meu banco, tenho esses campos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para pegar o nome dos meus cadastros existentes faço:

```
var db = getDataBase();
db.transaction(function(tx){
   tx.executeSql('SELECT nome FROM cartoes', [], function(tx, results){
        for(i=0; i<results.rows.lenght; i++){
              var nome = results.rows.item(i).nome;
              console.log(nome);
       }
   });

});
```

Como faço para pegar e atualizá-los na minha lista que foi inserida com append quando o usuário quiser ordenar pelo nome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Parece que esqueceu de adicionar algumas de suas tabelas, de qualquer forma, você pode remover os dados já adicionados na listagem com:

`$(".listagem").html('')`

E depois adicionar novamente com o mesmo append, pra isso poderia criar uma função que adiciona os valores:

```
function addRow(row){
     $(".listagem").append(SEU HTML);
}
```

E chamar ao clicar na ordenação chamar a função:

```
function ordenar(campo, direction = 'asc'){
    var db = getDataBase();
    db.transaction(function(tx){
       tx.executeSql('SELECT nome FROM cartoes order by '+campo + ' '+ direction, [], function(tx, results){
            for(i=0; i<results.rows.lenght; i++){
                  //chama função para adicionar os dados
                  addRow(results.rows.item(i));
           }
       });

    });
}
```

O order by fará com que os registros sejam ordenados pelo campo e na direção informados na função (`asc` ou `desc`)

Comment: function addRow(row){
     $(".listagem").append(SEU HTML);
}

nessa função eu adiciono meu html com os dados preenchidos? nome, id...

Comment: mais ou menos, você iria adicionar seu html pegando esses dados de row, exemplo `${row.nome}`, vi que tem outros dados que você utiliza dentro do html, mas não da pra saber de onde eles vem... Se puder melhorar a pergunta adicionando mais informações eu altero a minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui!

Answer (score 0):

Você ta utilizando um `for` e simplesmente adicionando os nomes, se você ordenar sua pesquisa provavelmente seu problema é resolvido.

Adicione um `ORDER BY` ao final do seu `SELECT`

```
SELECT nome FROM cartoes ORDER BY nome
```

Comment: Eu teria os nomes ordenados.. mas minha principal duvida é como atualizaria isso nos cadastros que foram inseridos com append.

Comment: Para ordenar no Javascript você pode usar a função `sort()`